# jasper grails parameters

Tags: grails, jasper-reports

I have a Jasper report which accepts an Integer parameter.
I am using the `<g:jasperReport>` tag to call the report. The body of this tag has an HTML `<input>` whose value gets passed to the report.

The report is not working. It is giving an `InvalidFormatException`.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Abe

Answer (score 0):

I found that defining the passed-in parameter as a `String` works even in the SQL; i.e., in the .jrxml:

```
<parameter name="headerid" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[ID this report is for]]></parameterDescription>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA['1']]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
```

Use it in the SQL as you would an Integer; i.e.:

```
where header.id = $P{headerid}
```